# Convergence of expectation of logarithms of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Let $\{ X_n \}$ be a sequence of random variables that converge to $X$ in distribution. Assume that $P\{X_n \geq 1\} = 1$ for all $n$, and that $\mathbb{E}X_n \rightarrow c < \infty$. Does it follow that $\mathbb{E}\{\log X_n\} \rightarrow \mathbb{E}\{\log X\}$?

I think I have an approximate solution by first noting the following four things:

1. Define $f_k(x) = k \wedge \log x$. Then, $f_k$ is bounded and continuous, and so, $\mathbb{E}f_k(X_n) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}f_k(X)$.
2. By monotone convergence theorem, $\mathbb{E}f_k(X) = \mathbb{E}(k \wedge \log X) \uparrow \mathbb{E}(\log X)$.
3. $\mathbb{E}X \leq \liminf_n \mathbb{E}X_n < \infty$.
4. $\mathbb{E}(\log X_n; X_n > K) = \int_K^\infty \log x \mathbb{P}(X_n \in dx) \leq \int_K^\infty \frac{\log K}{K} x \mathbb{P}(X_n \in dx) \leq \frac{\log K}{K} \mathbb{E}X_n \leq C \frac{\log K}{K}$

Using the four things above, I was able to bound $\mathbb{E} \lvert \log X_n - \log X \rvert$ using the $3\epsilon$ argument.

I am curious as to whether this is the correct approach and/or if there is a simpler, more intuitive way of solving the problem.

Comment: In the step 4., how do you obtain the first bound?

Comment: @DavideGiraudo if $x \geq K > 1$, then I think $\log x$ can be bounded above by the line passing through the origin and $(K,\log K)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can show that the sequence $(\log X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ satisfies the following properties:

- $\log X_n\to \log X$ in distribution;
- $\log X_n\geqslant 0$;
- $(\log X_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is uniformly integrable.

Define $Y_n:=\log X_n$. In order to check the third bullet, notice that $(e^{Y_n})\equiv (X_n)$ is bounded in $\mathbb L^1$.

(it is more or less what is suggested in the opening post)